# How to submit assignments to google classroom via API?

Tags: google-api, google-classroom, google-developers-console

I want to integrate Google classroom into my web application.

**Here is what I am able to do:**

1. Fetch Classrooms.
2. Fetch Students in each classroom.
3. Post Assignments in my app that are reflected back(or posted back as assignments) into the google classroom as well.

However now I want to update the completion status of each assignment by each student. If a student completes an assignment it should be reflected back into the classroom as well. Which API's should I call I've been through [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/turnIn). However I was unable to precisely identify the API call to modify the state of an assignment as "Completed".

**NOTE:**
I would also want to update the scores in the classrooms as well. If there's a way to update the scores/marks as well, It would be really helpful

Answer (score 2):

There is a property in courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions called [State](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions#state). The status when a students "completes" an assignment wherein he returns it to the teacher is called `TURNED_IN`.

Comment: Will it be possible to post grades as well?